# Function call to main

Tags: c

The objective is to display the word in "file.txt" that's between "} {". It runs when i write it in main() , but when I create a new funtion, and call that one in the main, it runs the code, but only to display nothing afterwords.

```
void listagem() {

    FILE *fp;
    char s[20],*l;

    fp = fopen("file.txt","r+");

    while((*l = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
            if (strcmp(l,"}") == 0)
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%[^{]", s);
                printf("%s", s);
                break;
            }
        }

    fclose(fp);
}

int main() {

    listagem();
}
```

The file has "We are }in{ 2019." written, so it should display "in" after running it,but it only does so when I run the code directly in "main()". When trying to run it in "listagem()" and then calling it in "main()", it displays nothing after running the program.

Comment: Several problems in your code.  Behaviour is undefined, since `l` is uninitialised, but there is an assignment to `*l`.   If it worked when the code was in `main()` rather than a separate function, then that is just happenstance.      `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`, and a `char` can never be equal to `EOF` so your loop would never terminate.  `strcmp()` assumes it is being passed an array that has a null terminator (which your code does not pass) and has undefined behaviour if it doesn't receive what it expects.

Comment: just use a plain `char` type, no pointer, and not `strcmp` but character equality

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `l` as a `char` pointer, but you never allocate memory for it.

```c
char *l = malloc(sizeof(*l));
if(l == NULL){
   printf("Could not allocate memory for character buffer.\n");
   return;
}
```

Make sure that you `free(l);` at the end of your function, as well.

**Edit:**
You probably want to add a newline (`\n`) to your `printf()` as well.